# How can i use multiply html files in webpack 4

Tags: webpack

I have one html file which works,but now i want to add another 4 html files.I googled,but i didnt't find answers.
I tried to copy the new HTML webpack plugin and there i insert the new name of the html file but when i try to acces i get error cannot get theName.html

```
THIS IS MY CONFIG FILE


var path = require('path')

const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports =  {
    module: {
        rules:[
            {
               test: /\.html$/,
               use:[
                   {
                       loader:"html-loader",
                       options:{minimize:true}
                   },
               ]
            },
            {
                test:/\.(jpg|png)$/,
                use:[
                    {
                        loader:'file-loader',
                        options:{
                            name:'[name].[ext]',
                            outputPath:'img/',
                            publicPath:'img/'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template:"./src/index.html",
            filename:"./index.html",
        }),
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you were right, you can simply duplicate the new HtmlWebPackPlugin

this one will work

```js
new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template:"src/index.html",
            filename:"index.html",
             inject: true
        },{

            template:"src/index-2.html",
            filename:"index-2.html",
            inject: true
}),
```

one more thing i want you to know.

if you have a running task like "npm run dev"

you have to stop it before editing the wepback.config file. and then run it again, otherwise webpack won't know about your changes.